# Facebook login returns error message if domain accessed without www prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have OmniAuthable Facebook login on my website. Users login with:

```
link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```

It is defined in app config at developers.facebook.com.

If I access the website through www.example.com, everything works ok and I can login.

If I access it without the "www" subdomain (i.e. example.com), I get the following response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: don't do that. You will end up with all sorts of problems (see [this page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/23650)). Choose to use either `www.example.com` or `example.com` and enforce it in your application by redirecting from the disallowed version to the desired one. FWIW, Google chooses to use `www` because it is more compatible with their architecture (indeed, it's more flexible). StackOverflow on the other hand chooses to go without it (it's canonically more accurate). Either way, pick one and stick with it.

Comment: It's probably because they've configured their app domain as 'www.yourdomain.com' instead of 'yourdomain'com' in their app settings, you can redirect to subdomains of what you've configured but you can't go up a level for security reasons

Comment: no, if i do the opposite, behaviour is the same (ie if i modify www.yourdomain.com in settings to yourdomain.com, i can login at yourdomain.com but i get an error at www.yourdomain.com)

Comment: ps. could you describe what kind of problems could i get if i have separate domain.com and www.domain.com? thing is new company i am working for does this mistake and i'd like to know how to explain them why this is wrong

Comment: Cookies are split and/or duplicated. SSL doesn't work. Inbound links aren't consistent.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the redirect from the disallowed version to the desired one - omniauth generates the routes automatically, when I try match "/auth/:provider" => redirect_to(my_allowed_domain), :constraints => {:subdomain => "www"} it doesn't seem to do anything